# Uploading as per the uploaded order in drag & drop functionality

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am uploading the images by drag & drop functionality using dropzone.js,
Here the issue I am facing is that, suppose if I've dragged 10 images together, then  all of them are start getting uploaded at a time.

Instead of that I need to allow in the order in which I have uploaded, means until the first one uploads completely the second image & the other images shouldn't be started.

Any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in documentation (http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_6), dropZone.js has a parallelUploads option. Set this option to 1, and it should solve your problem, no ?

Comment: yes there is an option, but before the first item gets uploaded completely the second is getting started, in the same way the remaining queue, but what actually needed is until the first item gets completed successfully or if it gets failed the second should not get started, but with this parallelUploads option it is uploading one after the other but during the time of the internal process of the first item(either the success or error) the second is getting started.

Comment: Well, it's maybe a bug and maybe related to this issue : https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/336 It's a bit similar to your problem, in a way that upload shows up as finished, while server side processing is not. It seems to be only a windows issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too, I answered in this thread:
[how to read list of files queued for dropzone and upload them in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970124/how-to-read-list-of-files-queued-for-dropzone-and-upload-them-in-order)

You need to wait for all the items to upload then process the uploaded list.
I create a global response array since I want info that came from the response of the upload.