# dropzone.js to be used as a simple <input type="file" multiple />

Tags: dropzone.js

What I would like to do, is to use dropzone.js as a drag&drop zone.

I don't want to upload the files, what I would like is to be able to access them and process them with jszip on the browser level (no server scripts, ajax etc.) using vanilla javascript.

I know how to process files from an  field, but I would like to combine this with DropZone.js as it is more user friendly (able to add/remove files, see thumbnails etc.)

The documentation is not very clear on the events to use, could someone give me a hand or a guiding direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right, found it.

```
myDropzone.files
```

<strike>myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles();</strike>

From here you can access the files and their details as if it where an html input field.

All info is in the [documentation](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/methods) in the end

Comment: merit goes partly to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970124/how-to-read-list-of-files-queued-for-dropzone-and-upload-them-in-order

Comment: and here: https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/417476-how-to-get-array-of-files-in-dropzone-and-submit-outside-of-dropzone/page__view__findpost__p__2406544?s=d452b505ae307fe3f5369d30950b0e7d